# Go micro rpc request slow for simple service

Tags: go, rpc, go-micro

I wrote a simple rpc service using go-micro, and I found each call would cost 1+ second, same in micro web. So I run official examples package and choose helloworld to test, and this happens again.

```
type Greeter struct{}

func (g *Greeter) Hello(ctx context.Context, req *proto.HelloRequest, rsp *proto.HelloResponse) error {
    rsp.Greeting = "Hello " + req.Name
    return nil
}

func main() {
    service := micro.NewService(
        micro.Name("greeter"),
    )

service.Init()

proto.RegisterGreeterHandler(service.Server(), new(Greeter))

if err := service.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Here are the results from executing a few sample requests:

```
started
Id:"1" UserName:"max"
1.099975019s
started
Id:"1" UserName:"max"
1.104435591s
started
Id:"1" UserName:"max"
1.103551837s
started
Id:"1" UserName:"max"
1.100724299s
started
Id:"1" UserName:"max"
1.098161724s
```

Can anyone tell me why each request takes so long?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the result as text. Should the image become unavailable, crucial information to the question would be missing. Furthermore, please at least give the import path of `micro`. Last but not least, what is the environment? Client? Language? Same machine, or accessing from half a world away? You get the picture...

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)‘s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its „harsh“ title.